# int conversion operator 'Class followed by int is illegal' return type of main should be 'int' not 'class'

Tags: c++

I'm teaching myself C++ right now from a book and one of the exercises is to program a class Date that converts a date it holds into a unique integer. However I can't figure out this error I'm getting when I run my program. I'm programming on C++ 2010.

The errors are:

`error C2628: 'Date' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)`

`error C3874: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'Date'`

What's odd is I tried to change my main to simply "return 0;" and the above errors still occur. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



class Date{
private:
    int day, month, year; //declaring variables

public:

    //declare constructor
    Date(int inputDay=1, int inputMonth=1, int inputYear=2012)
    :day(inputDay), month(inputMonth),year(inputYear){};

    // declare conversion operator for integers
    operator int(){
        return year*10000+month*100+day;
    }
}



int main() {
    Date today(25,11,2012);
    return today;
    //doesn't matter if I delete above 2 lines and write return 0; both errors still occur
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `;` after the class definition.

Comment: I'm ashamed to have asked this

Comment: @Chowza: The irony is that your compiler actually told you this :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Ha I know now it's so obvious. I was looking at my constructor wondering where I had an integer and where the semicolon was missing...

Comment: @Chowza: As an additional piece of irony, you actually have an *extraneous* semi-colon after your constructor body... some compilers have a warning for that, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB that's interesting. The book I'm learning from has that semi colon after all the list initialization examples. Perhaps a case of a book with typos or being outdated. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the following code answers your query!

```
#include <iostream.h>

class Date
{
private:
int day, month, year; //declaring variables
long int result;

public:

//declare constructor
Date(int inputDay, int inputMonth, int inputYear)
{
this.day=inputDay;
this.month=inputMonth;
this.year=inputYear;
// declare conversion operator for integers
result=year*10000+month*100+day;
cout<<"Result = "<<result<<"\n";
}
};


int main() 
{
Date today(25,11,2012);
return 0;
}
```